# Epic launch context token EPICUSERID

Tags: hl7-fhir

When launching an App Orchard app from Epic we can pass some context tokens. One being the currently logged in user id. 
It seems however that the ID is being prepended with a plus sign "+". And in some cases multiple pluses I'm guessing to make an ID a certain length.

What's the reason for these plus signs?

Comment: App Orchard questions may be better directed to your App Orchard rep, rather than asked on StackOverflow.  Many AO-related questions won't be related to programming topics and might get closed as not being appropriate for StackOverflow.

Comment: I don't know that I agree. I'm looking for developer community to help navigate the App Orchard ad Epic integration projects. There isn't a community that is setup by Epic specifically , so looking for a broader audience that can help. I'm sure others may be running into same issues as I am and it would be good to share the knowledge. In fact you did help significantly to resolve an issue App Orchard team wasn't able to.

Comment: @HIT_girl, any solution?